"тяжёл" и "тЯжел". Возможны ли оба варианта?
Есть ли вариант чтения и записи слова "тяжёл" через "е" - "тЯжел" (ударение на "я")? Если есть, то когда используется?

Наверняка, в каком-нибудь говоре найдётся

Тяжел другое слово. Что оно обозначает я не знаю.
